# Does a Kazakh need a visa for stopovers in Seoul and walking in the city?

Tags: transit-visas, seoul, kazakh-citizens

I am Kazakhstani citizen flying from Australia to Kazakhstan with a long - 23 hours- stopover in Seoul Incheon Airport, and the same stopover on my way back. While stopping there I would like to walk in Seoul and get a hotel.

Do I need a visa for this?

Answer (score 4):

According to Timatic:

> Korea (Rep. of), South - Destination Visa
>
> Visa required.
>
> The following are exempt from holding a visa:
>
> Nationals of Kazakhstan
> with a normal passport for a maximum stay of 30 days.

Thus you don't need a visa for this. Note that there's also a hotel in the airport itself, which might be more comfortable if you have an early flight.

Note that the trains to airport do not run at night; as far as I remember, there are no trains between midnight and 5:30am.